# Gradle add library to classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using Gradle for a project. My build.gradle has got JUnit as a dependency, but every time I import the project again it does not recognize the JUnit library and asks me to add it to classpath. This problem does not only apply to JUnit, but also to other dependencies. Did I add JUnit to the wrong place?

PS: The project builds just fine, it's just the IDE (IntelliJ) that's marking everything red.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Try adding to Gradle like this: testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' and in your clases: import org.junit.Test;

Comment: @JoseGonzalez that doesn't help. The import ist also correct...

Comment: Please add the Gradle and IDEA versions to the question. Also, in the `Project` side window, under `External Libraries`, do you see `Gradle: junit:junit:4.11`?

Comment: The code file that you're editing, what folder does it live in? For `testCompile` to have any affect, the file should be in `src/test/java` or similar.

Comment: @PaoloFulgoni IntelliJ Idea 15.0.3 (Ultimate), Gradle 2 (At least, not sure which version). Under Project Structure, Libraries I can see Gradle: junit:junit:4.11

Comment: @RaGe it is, the tests are executed correctly using Gradle.

Comment: @ElMac everything looks good. Please add a piece of code and the related error which you get from IDEA

Comment: @PaoloFulgoni I show the error on the image I posted. I can't show you more because there is nothing more. It's the common error you would have if you dont add a library to the class path. I don't know what causes it. I will try doing some updates...

Comment: So updated Gradle to last version. IntelliJ is also last version. I must say this is a multi-project gradle setup, maybe that's important, maybe not.

Comment: Did it end good?

Comment: @JuanJoséMeleroGómez I dont remember what project that was. Can't tell :/.

Comment: @ElMac Hahahahahahaha. Alright. In my case, I was importing the dependencies in a different module from the one where I wanted to use them.

Answer (score 10):

The dependency declaration is correct. Probably you're opening the project in IntelliJ IDEA the wrong way.

I suggest you to open a Gradle project this way:

1. Click the `File | Open` menu
2. Select the `build.gradle` file

Here is further information about [importing Gradle projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-gradle-model.html) (see also the side note in that page).

Comment: I do open it like described there. It detects it as Gradle project also... I just have to resolve the errors (easy to do, but if I am using Gradle I would like to run smooth). My guess could be that maybe I have the dependency set for a wrong JUnit version...

Comment: @El Mac that doesn't make sense, the other dependency only exists in one version and it has the same problem.

Comment: @ElMac - Did you resolve the issue? I'm seeing the same issue with a different artifact.

Comment: I had to close the project and reopen it in order for intellij to detect it as a gradle project

Answer (score 2):

download the external jar file from mvn repository and add it to libs folder.

1. Gradle-project(your project)->libs(inside libs folder paste jar file). if you don't have libs folder just create it.
2. go to build.gradle
   dependencies {  compile files('libs/your_jar.jar') }
3. reload the gradle project.

it's worked for me. i hope it's work for you guys also...